# How to pass a parameter to the viewmodel of the navigated page without mvvm light

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to pass a parameter "Trip" to the viewmodel of my navigated page. So far, i have this:
the code of my page from which i will navigate from. Its a Flip of trips

```
public sealed partial class TripOverview : Page
{
    public TripOverview()
    {
        
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new TripOverviewViewmodel();

    }
    public void Trip_Detail(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Trip selectedTrip = (Trip)TripFlip.SelectedItem;
        
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(TripDetail), selectedTrip);
        
    }
    
}
```

this is my Trip detail page. I want to add the parameter that i get from the onNavigatedTo method to the viewmodel which i then link to the Datacontext.

```
public sealed partial class TripDetail : Page
   
{
    public Trip selectedTrip { get; set; }
    public TripDetailViewmodel vm = new TripDetailViewmodel();
    
    public TripDetail()
    {
        
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = vm;
       


    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Trip trip = (Trip)e.Parameter;
        
        
        
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }




}
```

So basicly i want the property "currentTrip in my viewmodel:

```
 public class TripDetailViewmodel
{

    public Trip CurrentTrip { get; set; }
    public TripDetailViewmodel()
    {
       
    }
    
   
}
```

to be set without the use of mvvm light

Here is the XAML of my TripDetail page

```
<Page
x:Class="TravelChecker.TripDetail"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TravelChecker"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:viewmodel="using:TravelChecker.Viewmod"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:TripDetailViewmodel x:Name="tripsDetailVm" />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="title" Text="{x:Bind tripsDetailVm.CurrentTrip.Destination.LocationName}"
                           FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="26.667" 
                           Foreground="Black" Padding="15,20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.318,0.392" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=title, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="titletxt">
        
    </TextBox>
    
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you post your XAML for this Page? In order to set this you'd need to make your view model a property (instead of a field) and set the bindings in the XAML.

Comment: Could you please tell me is the MVVM light means the MVVM Light Toolkit? You could try to add the code  `vm.CurrentTrip = trip;` in the OnNavigatedTo of the TripDetail page. 
Please let me know if the code meet your requirements.

Comment: Ill update the post with the XAML.

Comment: Adding that line doesnt work because the onnavigatedto is called to late. Its builds the page first and then initialize the vm. I want to initialize the vm before the page is created or atleast refresh the page after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [{x:Bind}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#property-path-resolution) to implement the data binding, the default source is the page instead of the `DataContext`. **{x:Bind}** will look in the code-behind of your page for properties, fields, and methods. To expose your view model to **{x:Bind}**, you will typically want to add new fields or properties to the code behind for your page.

But if you use [{Binding}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/binding-markup-extension) to implement data binding, **{Binding}** will need the `DataContext`.

Therefore, you could select the `tripsDetailVm` which is created in XAML’s `Page.DataContext` tag or the `vm` which is created in code behind as the binding source. However, whichever binding source you select, you need to set the `CurrentTrip` property as `trip`.

When you use `tripsDetailVm`  as `DataContext`, you need to add the code `tripsDetailVm.CurrentTrip = trip;` to `OnNavigatedTo` method. Then **{x:Bind}** could find `tripsDetailVm.CurrentTrip.Destination.LocationName` in page and **{Binding}** could find `title` in `DataContext`(that is `tripsDetailVm`). Though the `vm` is initialized later than the page built, but it does not matter.